# TensorFlow CNN Tutorial: How to edit top layer to be locally connected?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I have some background in machine learning and python, but I am just learning TensorFlow. I am going through the [tutorial on deep convolutional neural nets](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn/) to teach myself how to use it for image classification. Along the way there is an exercise, which I am having trouble completing.

**EXERCISE:** The model architecture in inference() differs slightly from the CIFAR-10 model specified in cuda-convnet. In particular, the top layers of Alex's original model are locally connected and not fully connected. Try editing the architecture to exactly reproduce the locally connected architecture in the top layer.

The exercise refers to the inference() function in the [cifar10.py model](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10.py). The 2nd to last layer (called local4) has a shape=[384, 192], and the top layer has a shape=[192, NUM_CLASSES], where NUM_CLASSES=10 of course. I think the code that we are asked to edit is somewhere in the code defining the top layer:

```
with tf.variable_scope('softmax_linear') as scope:
    weights = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', [192, NUM_CLASSES],
                                      stddev=1/192.0, wd=0.0)
    biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [NUM_CLASSES],
                          tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
    softmax_linear = tf.add(tf.matmul(local4, weights), biases,name=scope.name
    _activation_summary(softmax_linear)
```

But I don't see any code that determines the probability of connecting between layers, so I don't know how we can change the model from fully connected to locally connected. Does somebody know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm also working on this exercise. I'll try and explain my approach properly, rather than just give the solution. It's worth looking back at the mathematics of a fully connected layer (https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners).

So the linear algebra for a fully connected layer is:

*y = W * x + b*

where *x* is the n dimensional input vector, *b* is an *n* dimensional vector of biases, and *W* is an *n*-by-*n* matrix of weights. The *i* th element of *y* is the sum of the *i* th row of W multiplied element-wise with *x*.

So....if you only want *y[i]* connected to *x[i-1]*, *x[i]*, and *x[i+1]*, you simply set all values in the *i* th row of *W* to zero, apart from the *(i-1)* th, *i* th and *(i+1)* th column of that row. Therefore to create a locally connected layer, you simply enforce *W* to be a banded matrix (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_matrix), where the size of the band is equal to the size of the locally connected neighbourhoods you want. Tensorflow has a function for setting a matrix to be banded (`tf.batch_matrix_band_part(input, num_lower, num_upper, name=None)`).

This seems to me to be the simplest mathematical solution to the exercise.

Comment: This answer does not solve the exercise. The W matrix has to be "multi-banded". For example, if the filter is 3x3, then there should be 3 diagonal bands, 3 element wide each. tf.matrix_band_part() only allows one band.
Also, the dimensions of W will change, we can't just take the original W and set some elements to zero. Specifically, the number of rows in W must be equal to the length of the flattened output feature map. 

I think Xyand's answer is a better approach: extract image patches, and multiply each by its own kernel, so weights tensor gains two extra dimensions (becomes 6D).

Comment: Fair enough. This was just me trying to get some sort of grasp of the mathematics to give a clue as to how to solve this exercise. I assume the reason they give exercises is to get people to think for themselves, so I wasn't really trying to just give some code that could be copy/pasted, but to help get a basic understanding of how this could be approached theoretically. I find it helpful to understand some of the linear algebra when working with neural nets, rather than just the engineering.

Comment: It has been a while since I dealt with this locally connected layer. But  the approach by @DavidPickup can actually work by simulating multi banded matrix with a full matrix multiplied by a constant indicator matrix, I. The size of W should be (w_out*h_out) X (w_in*h_in*d_in). However it seems quite wasteful. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sure, we could construct such indicator matrix by inserting multiple single-band matrices at regular intervals.  Aside from a much larger (but sparse) W, we would introduce extra computation: backpropagation would try to update those zero weight values, so we would have to perform W*I after every weight update (or W_grad*I before every update). This overhead is might be significant: if we assume W*I is as expensive as W*x, we have to do ~33% more work (masking, forward pass, backward pass) vs just forward and backward passes.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to answer your question although I'm not 100% I got it right as well.

Looking at the cuda-convnet [architecture](https://github.com/akrizhevsky/cuda-convnet2/blob/master/layers/layers-cifar10-11pct.cfg) we can see that the TensorFlow and cuda-convnet implementations start to differ after the second pooling layer.

TensorFlow implementation implements two fully connected layers and softmax classifier.

cuda-convnet implements two locally connected layers, one fully connected layer and softmax classifier.

The code snippet you included refers only to the softmax classifier and is in fact shared between the two implementations. To reproduce the cuda-convnet implementation using TensorFlow we have to replace the existing fully connected layers with two locally connected layers and a fully connected one.

Since Tensor doesn't have locally connected layers as part of the SDK we have to figure out a way to implement it using the existing tools. Here is my attempt to implement the first locally connected layers:

```
  with tf.variable_scope('local3') as scope:
    shape = pool2.get_shape()
    h = shape[1].value
    w = shape[2].value

    sz_local = 3 # kernel size
    sz_patch = (sz_local**2)*shape[3].value
    n_channels = 64

    # Extract 3x3 tensor patches
    patches = tf.extract_image_patches(pool2, [1,sz_local,sz_local,1], [1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,1], 'SAME')
    weights = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[1,h,w,sz_patch, n_channels], stddev=5e-2, wd=0.0)
    biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [h,w,n_channels], tf.constant_initializer(0.1))

    # "Filter" each patch with its own kernel 
    mul = tf.multiply(tf.expand_dims(patches, axis=-1), weights)
    ssum = tf.reduce_sum(mul, axis=3)
    pre_activation = tf.add(ssum, biases)
    local3 = tf.nn.relu(pre_activation, name=scope.name)
```

Comment: h and w dimensions in weights shape should refer to output feature map height and width, not to the input feature map.